# Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js' when deploying node.js to heroku:

Tags: node.js, heroku

This works perfectly fine locally, I've been looking through all of heroku's node deployment related documentation but haven't been able to find the solution there.

This is my terminal view after building with the first error:

terminal log after running 'git push heroku master
[image]

terminal log after running 'heroku logs'
[image]

Comment: Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: Please add text code instead of code in image. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer